# How do I configure crosstools-ng sample for cross compiling toolchain for my router?

Tags: ssh, mips, cross-compiling, router, openwrt

I want to cross compile shadowsocks for my router ( netcore q3, made in china) on CentOS 7. So I got crosstools-ng, I ssh into the router, and get following info (The router is on a Tomato Firmware 1.28.0000 MIPSR2-131 K26 Max by shibby), I used [How to build a cross compiler for your Raspberry Pi](http://www.bootc.net/archives/2012/05/26/how-to-build-a-cross-compiler-for-your-raspberry-pi/) as my reference

```
$less /proc/cpuinfo
system type             : Broadcom BCM53572 chip rev 1 pkg 8
processor               : 0
cpu model               : MIPS 74K V4.9
BogoMIPS                : 149.50
cpu MHz                 : 300
wait instruction        : no
microsecond timers      : yes
tlb_entries             : 32
extra interrupt vector  : no
hardware watchpoint     : yes
ASEs implemented        : mips16 dsp
shadow register sets    : 1
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available

unaligned_instructions  : 0
```

I also copied a .so file from /lib

```
$ scp root@router:/lib/libc.so.0 .

[oglop@localhost tmp]$ readelf -h libc.so.0 
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           MIPS R3000
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x6d50
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          260672 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x50001007, noreorder, pic, cpic, o32, mips32
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         5
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         18
  Section header string table index: 17
```

files in /lib on the router

```
root@unknown:/tmp/home/root# ls /lib
ld-uClibc.so.0                libgcc_s.so.1                 libutil.so.0
libc.so.0                     libm.so.0                     modules
libcrypt.so.0                 libnsl.so.0                   openvpn_plugin_auth_nvram.so
libdl.so.0                    libpthread.so.0
```

Can I get all the information from these two? Which sample should I choose ?
So from the .so file :

```
endianness : little endian
bitness: ?
abi: ?
target os: linux or bare-metal?
c library: glibc, musl or uClibc ?
...
```

I guess I should starts with `mips-unknown-linux-uclibc` and change it to little endian ?

```
[oglop@localhost tmp]$ ct-ng list-samples | grep mips
[G.X]   mips64el-n32-linux-uclibc
[G.X]   mips64el-n64-linux-uclibc
[G..]   mips-ar2315-linux-gnu
[G..]   mipsel-sde-elf
[G..]   mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu
[G..]   mips-malta-linux-gnu
[G..]   mips-unknown-elf
[G..]   mips-unknown-linux-uclibc

root@unknown:/tmp/home/root# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.22.19 (root@tomato) (gcc version 4.2.4) #16 Tue Aug 4 00:16:31 CEST 2015
```

I tried to figure out the libc version tomato uses, but

```
root@unknown:/tmp/home/root# /lib/libc.so.0 
Segmentation fault
root@unknown:/tmp/home/root# ldd --version
-sh: --version: not found
```

Or Can I get the info I need from tomato source shibby branch on [github](https://github.com/tomatofirmware/tomato)?